Crash when parsing a CSV file (stored on iCloud)
When trying to read a csv file (which is stored in the download folder of icloudDrive) my app is always crashing with this error:
The view service did terminate with error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}
I don't really know what the problem is and google did't solve this either. I checked if the environments objects are alle passed to the view. They are and are all initialized.
Here is the code:

import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct CSVView: View {
    @State private var openFile = false
    @State private var contacts: [Contact] = []
    
    @EnvironmentObject var contactManager: ContactManager
    @EnvironmentObject var organizationManager: OrganizationManager
    @EnvironmentObject var groupManager: GroupManager
    @EnvironmentObject var departmentManager: DepartmentManager
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("CSV-Datei importieren")
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Image("icon-import")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                    
                    Button(action: { openFile.toggle() }, label: {
                        Text("Öffnen")
                    })
                    .buttonStyle(Button_blue())
                    .padding()
                }
                .fileImporter(
                    isPresented: $openFile,
                    allowedContentTypes: [.commaSeparatedText],
                    allowsMultipleSelection: false
                ) { result in
                    handleFileImport(result: result)
                }
                .navigationTitle("Datenbank Import/Export")
                .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
                .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                
                VStack {
                    Text("CSV-Datei exportieren")
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Image("icon-export")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                    
                    Button(action: { /* Implement export functionality */ }, label: {
                        Text("Speichern")
                    })
                    .buttonStyle(Button_blue())
                    .padding()
                }
                .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
                .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func handleFileImport(result: Result<[URL], Error>) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            do {
                let fileURL = try result.get().first
                guard let fileURL = fileURL else { return }
                
                if fileURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
                    defer { fileURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
                    
                    if let content = try? String(contentsOf: fileURL) {
                        let parsedContacts = parseCSV(content: content)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            contacts = parsedContacts
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("Unable to read file contents: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func parseCSV(content: String) -> [Contact] {
        var contactsRead: [Contact] = []
        let rows = content.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        
        for (index, row) in rows.enumerated() {
            if index == 0 { continue } // Skip header row
            
            let columns = row.components(separatedBy: ",")
            if columns.count >= 6 {
                let contact = Contact(
                    id: UUID().uuidString,
                    vorname: columns[0].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
                    nachname: columns[1].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
                    titel: columns[2].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
                    bezeichnung: columns[3].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
                    organization: columns[4].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
                    group: columns[5].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
                    department: "",
                    telArbeit: "",
                    telMobil: groupManager.selectedGroup.id,
                    email: "",
                    passwort: "",
                    strasse: "",
                    plz: "",
                    stadt: "",
                    land: "",
                    hasMoreOrganizations: false,
                    isPerson: true,
                    moreOrganizations: [],
                    isAdmin: false,
                    isSuperAdmin: false,
                    adminPermissions: [],
                    lastEdited: FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp(date: Date()),
                    editor: contactManager.currentContact?.id ?? ""
                )
                contactsRead.append(contact)
            }
        }
        
        return contactsRead
    }
}


Probably not related to your actual problem, I’d recommend a real CSV parser like, https://github.com/dehesa/CodableCSV, or https://github.com/swiftcsv/SwiftCSV.
